# Elementary set equivalence proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Given the sets $A = \{x | x = 2j + 1, \quad j \geq 0\}$ and $B = \{x | x = 2k - 1, \quad k \geq 1\}$ prove $A = B$.

My proof is as follows:

$$\forall x \in A, \quad x = 2j+1$$

$$2j + 1 + 1 - 1 = 2j + 2 - 1 = 2(j+1) - 1 \therefore j+1 = k$$

$$A \subseteq B \quad \square$$

$$\forall x \in B, \quad x = 2k-1$$

$$2k - 1 - 1 + 1 = 2k - 2 = 1 = 2(k-1) + 1 \therefore k-1 = j$$

$$B \subseteq A \quad \square$$

$$\text{If} \quad A \subseteq B \quad \text{and} \quad B \subseteq A \quad \text{then} \quad A = B$$

Is this a sufficient proof, just proving that we can put $j$ in terms of $k$ with the conditions still holding, and vice versa?

### Edit: Auxiliary

Also if there are any notation errors please let me know, I'd like to refine my knowledge.

Comment: One piece of advice in general is to use words where symbols could work. It helps the reader parse your proof, and it is good practice to say "for each $x$" instead of "$\forall x$." Granted, it's a minor detail, but one to keep in mind moving forward, as this proof is mostly symbols. Your proof looks good, but I would say, "since $j + 1$ is an integer greater than or equal to $1$, we have the desired inclusion" instead of $\therefore j + 1 = k$.

Comment: @AOrtiz thanks a lot. Yeah my discrete prof was going crazy with symbols today and I think it sacrificed clarity...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. However, your notation is confusing at times, especially the $\therefore j + 1 = k$ part. It is not really clear what you mean by that statement: you should write in words, "therefore if we let $k = j + 1$, the resulting number $x = 2k - 1$ is a member of $B$, and hence..." As @AOrtiz said, "use words where symbols could work".

The proof has various equivalent statements: by proving a bijection between the sets, by expressing the elements as recurrences, etc. but all will follow the same structure. You could try writing them out and see which one you think is the simplest to write and follow.

Comment: Ok so the point is not to just write out the result `k = j + 1` but explain why that result gives us the necessary inclusion that follows the set's intensional definition? I think that makes sense, thanks a lot